# Extracting correct value from a string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I am trying to parse data provided by youtube and the data we received comes jumbled up, as shown below:

```
var str1 = "sp=sig&s=VQ%3DQP9RU7Lk%3DNY8A2K77AqlhtQFHhgjwUKJ7AIJlMRFv3zAEiAOkJ3YA-44rCPLIGBJnwPdO0uj40Z7mljzZ2AXCvRi1KAhIgRww2IxgLALP&url=https%3A%2F%2Fr5---sn-cvh76nes.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fexpire%3D1568300957%26ei%3DPQt6XY7IAve61Abrw6_wAQ%26ip%3D117.204.241.200%26id%3Do-ALVM4ikuXaCe79Biki6ND2_b9Tcbu8lq4-lMLv3LHEve%26itag%3D43%26source%3Dyoutube%26requiressl%3Dyes%26mm%3D31%252C26%26mn%3Dsn-cvh76nes%252Csn-h557sns7%26ms%3Dau%252Conr%26mv%3Dm%26mvi%3D4%26pl%3D24%26initcwndbps%3D200000%26mime%3Dvideo%252Fwebm%26gir%3Dyes%26clen%3D15541206%26ratebypass%3Dyes%26dur%3D0.000%26lmt%3D1567892283575963%26mt%3D1568279236%26fvip%3D5%26c%3DWEB%26txp%3D5511222%26sparams%3Dexpire%252Cei%252Cip%252Cid%252Citag%252Csource%252Crequiressl%252Cmime%252Cgir%252Cclen%252Cratebypass%252Cdur%252Clmt%26lsparams%3Dmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cmvi%252Cpl%252Cinitcwndbps%26lsig%3DAHylml4wRQIhAI3rDvKBNzfeh9dyIFzgVC0fZ4iloNfBwPuMRlZnKJnGAiAxEYb5hDuizUHBXub1TfLiEpE2JkKYA4PFeguH8izQmg%253D%253D";
```

or this:

```
var str2 = "url=https%3A%2F%2Fr5---sn-cvh76nes.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fexpire%3D1568301634%26ei%3D4g16XbD5JZ6H3LUP0d-WyAo%26ip%3D117.204.241.200%26id%3Do-AJq_yac4GJRrnb7CPAFTFaQqfK4NBUzepYOo07WdMVK9%26itag%3D18%26source%3Dyoutube%26requiressl%3Dyes%26mm%3D31%252C26%26mn%3Dsn-cvh76nes%252Csn-h557sns7%26ms%3Dau%252Conr%26mv%3Dm%26mvi%3D4%26pl%3D24%26initcwndbps%3D188750%26mime%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%26gir%3Dyes%26clen%3D11441933%26ratebypass%3Dyes%26dur%3D165.720%26lmt%3D1567716422140989%26mt%3D1568279980%26fvip%3D5%26c%3DWEB%26txp%3D6311222%26sparams%3Dexpire%252Cei%252Cip%252Cid%252Citag%252Csource%252Crequiressl%252Cmime%252Cgir%252Cclen%252Cratebypass%252Cdur%252Clmt%26lsparams%3Dmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cmvi%252Cpl%252Cinitcwndbps%26lsig%3DAHylml4wRQIhALYdxd4qwK4dT3-6pUN9Elb2jUHR9OZ2w-oaJ1fj5djdAiB_pGo5784Uhu0VKT9p6O366IyaQzKanI4seyKm1t-UaA%253D%253D&sp=sig&s=H%3D%3D%3Dgmz8buy%3Dhsmd9mFSGKhiwwvA2HUf1ko1mkPNoh_nFIrDQICIru6A35uuX-_l_IAN41kPp2Zm637tiEGnBtmPaXEhbPgIQRww2IxgLALh";
```

I need to extract value of `url`, `sp` and `sig` for processing but having a hard time getting them through regex. Here is what I tried - https://js.do/code/ytjumble but since the position of `url`, `sp` and `sig` are getting changed we cannot rely on `split` method. Also, the regex used to get the url fetches an extra `2F` value.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Examples

Comment: Your first input has values for `sp` and `s` only. Your second input only has `url`. `sig` isn't available in either. Please clarify your question

Comment: @CinCout Pls. check again it has the url value

Comment: @User863 Tried this - https://js.do/code/ytjumble2 but the results are not working if url key is first. Will try your example.

Comment: @CinCout This seems to be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query string starts with `?` try concat it

```
getParameterByName('url', '?' + str2);
```

```js
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
  if (!url) url = window.location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
  var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
    results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return '';
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

var str = "sp=sig&s=VQ%3DQP9RU7Lk%3DNY8A2K77AqlhtQFHhgjwUKJ7AIJlMRFv3zAEiAOkJ3YA-44rCPLIGBJnwPdO0uj40Z7mljzZ2AXCvRi1KAhIgRww2IxgLALP&url=https%3A%2F%2Fr5---sn-cvh76nes.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fexpire%3D1568300957%26ei%3DPQt6XY7IAve61Abrw6_wAQ%26ip%3D117.204.241.200%26id%3Do-ALVM4ikuXaCe79Biki6ND2_b9Tcbu8lq4-lMLv3LHEve%26itag%3D43%26source%3Dyoutube%26requiressl%3Dyes%26mm%3D31%252C26%26mn%3Dsn-cvh76nes%252Csn-h557sns7%26ms%3Dau%252Conr%26mv%3Dm%26mvi%3D4%26pl%3D24%26initcwndbps%3D200000%26mime%3Dvideo%252Fwebm%26gir%3Dyes%26clen%3D15541206%26ratebypass%3Dyes%26dur%3D0.000%26lmt%3D1567892283575963%26mt%3D1568279236%26fvip%3D5%26c%3DWEB%26txp%3D5511222%26sparams%3Dexpire%252Cei%252Cip%252Cid%252Citag%252Csource%252Crequiressl%252Cmime%252Cgir%252Cclen%252Cratebypass%252Cdur%252Clmt%26lsparams%3Dmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cmvi%252Cpl%252Cinitcwndbps%26lsig%3DAHylml4wRQIhAI3rDvKBNzfeh9dyIFzgVC0fZ4iloNfBwPuMRlZnKJnGAiAxEYb5hDuizUHBXub1TfLiEpE2JkKYA4PFeguH8izQmg%253D%253D";
var str2 = "url=https%3A%2F%2Fr5---sn-cvh76nes.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fexpire%3D1568301634%26ei%3D4g16XbD5JZ6H3LUP0d-WyAo%26ip%3D117.204.241.200%26id%3Do-AJq_yac4GJRrnb7CPAFTFaQqfK4NBUzepYOo07WdMVK9%26itag%3D18%26source%3Dyoutube%26requiressl%3Dyes%26mm%3D31%252C26%26mn%3Dsn-cvh76nes%252Csn-h557sns7%26ms%3Dau%252Conr%26mv%3Dm%26mvi%3D4%26pl%3D24%26initcwndbps%3D188750%26mime%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%26gir%3Dyes%26clen%3D11441933%26ratebypass%3Dyes%26dur%3D165.720%26lmt%3D1567716422140989%26mt%3D1568279980%26fvip%3D5%26c%3DWEB%26txp%3D6311222%26sparams%3Dexpire%252Cei%252Cip%252Cid%252Citag%252Csource%252Crequiressl%252Cmime%252Cgir%252Cclen%252Cratebypass%252Cdur%252Clmt%26lsparams%3Dmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cmvi%252Cpl%252Cinitcwndbps%26lsig%3DAHylml4wRQIhALYdxd4qwK4dT3-6pUN9Elb2jUHR9OZ2w-oaJ1fj5djdAiB_pGo5784Uhu0VKT9p6O366IyaQzKanI4seyKm1t-UaA%253D%253D&sp=sig&s=H%3D%3D%3Dgmz8buy%3Dhsmd9mFSGKhiwwvA2HUf1ko1mkPNoh_nFIrDQICIru6A35uuX-_l_IAN41kPp2Zm637tiEGnBtmPaXEhbPgIQRww2IxgLALh";

var result = getParameterByName('url', '?' + str);
document.write(result);

document.write("<br><br><br>");

var result = getParameterByName('url', '?' + str2);
document.write(result);
```

Using `URLSearchParams()`

```js
var str = "sp=sig&s=VQ%3DQP9RU7Lk%3DNY8A2K77AqlhtQFHhgjwUKJ7AIJlMRFv3zAEiAOkJ3YA-44rCPLIGBJnwPdO0uj40Z7mljzZ2AXCvRi1KAhIgRww2IxgLALP&url=https%3A%2F%2Fr5---sn-cvh76nes.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fexpire%3D1568300957%26ei%3DPQt6XY7IAve61Abrw6_wAQ%26ip%3D117.204.241.200%26id%3Do-ALVM4ikuXaCe79Biki6ND2_b9Tcbu8lq4-lMLv3LHEve%26itag%3D43%26source%3Dyoutube%26requiressl%3Dyes%26mm%3D31%252C26%26mn%3Dsn-cvh76nes%252Csn-h557sns7%26ms%3Dau%252Conr%26mv%3Dm%26mvi%3D4%26pl%3D24%26initcwndbps%3D200000%26mime%3Dvideo%252Fwebm%26gir%3Dyes%26clen%3D15541206%26ratebypass%3Dyes%26dur%3D0.000%26lmt%3D1567892283575963%26mt%3D1568279236%26fvip%3D5%26c%3DWEB%26txp%3D5511222%26sparams%3Dexpire%252Cei%252Cip%252Cid%252Citag%252Csource%252Crequiressl%252Cmime%252Cgir%252Cclen%252Cratebypass%252Cdur%252Clmt%26lsparams%3Dmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cmvi%252Cpl%252Cinitcwndbps%26lsig%3DAHylml4wRQIhAI3rDvKBNzfeh9dyIFzgVC0fZ4iloNfBwPuMRlZnKJnGAiAxEYb5hDuizUHBXub1TfLiEpE2JkKYA4PFeguH8izQmg%253D%253D";
var str2 = "url=https%3A%2F%2Fr5---sn-cvh76nes.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fexpire%3D1568301634%26ei%3D4g16XbD5JZ6H3LUP0d-WyAo%26ip%3D117.204.241.200%26id%3Do-AJq_yac4GJRrnb7CPAFTFaQqfK4NBUzepYOo07WdMVK9%26itag%3D18%26source%3Dyoutube%26requiressl%3Dyes%26mm%3D31%252C26%26mn%3Dsn-cvh76nes%252Csn-h557sns7%26ms%3Dau%252Conr%26mv%3Dm%26mvi%3D4%26pl%3D24%26initcwndbps%3D188750%26mime%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%26gir%3Dyes%26clen%3D11441933%26ratebypass%3Dyes%26dur%3D165.720%26lmt%3D1567716422140989%26mt%3D1568279980%26fvip%3D5%26c%3DWEB%26txp%3D6311222%26sparams%3Dexpire%252Cei%252Cip%252Cid%252Citag%252Csource%252Crequiressl%252Cmime%252Cgir%252Cclen%252Cratebypass%252Cdur%252Clmt%26lsparams%3Dmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cmvi%252Cpl%252Cinitcwndbps%26lsig%3DAHylml4wRQIhALYdxd4qwK4dT3-6pUN9Elb2jUHR9OZ2w-oaJ1fj5djdAiB_pGo5784Uhu0VKT9p6O366IyaQzKanI4seyKm1t-UaA%253D%253D&sp=sig&s=H%3D%3D%3Dgmz8buy%3Dhsmd9mFSGKhiwwvA2HUf1ko1mkPNoh_nFIrDQICIru6A35uuX-_l_IAN41kPp2Zm637tiEGnBtmPaXEhbPgIQRww2IxgLALh";

var str2Params = a = new URLSearchParams("?" + str2)
console.log(str2Params.get('url'))
```